# Programatically supplying credentials to DSN connection used by Power Query

Tags: excel, credentials, powerquery, dsn, vba

We have an oracle database that can be accessed with a general-purpose, read-only account.  Connection information is stored as DSN.

I have created a 2016 Excel Workbook that uses Power Query and the DSN connection information.  I want to be able to circulate the workbook, but when a new user opens it, the cached credentials are lost and the user would be prompted to enter the needed information.

I have suppressed application warnings during the load to avoid the annoying 'approve native query' pop-up caused by Power Query.  However, this means that the credentials box, if needed, is also is not displayed.  Therefore, the query runs without a password and fails.

Is there a way I can programmatically update the credentials?

Comment: I have no idea if using this method will work with a DSN connection, but this page has been helpful https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2017/08/08/saving-sql-passwords-in-excel-power-pivot-connections/

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Mistella.  Sadly, it doesn't quite describe my use case.  I'll have to try solving this from another angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported because, in general, storing credentials within the document is a security risk.

The credentials dialog does not depend on the native query dialog. It doesn't appear if you already have credentials for the data source. You can clear or edit these credentials in the Data Source settings window, which is accessible from the File menu in the Query Editor.

Comment: We run a query that is modified in vba based on selections the user makes on the worksheet.  This altered query is run which then produces the Native Query dialog.  Most of our users do not understand SQL or databases and are confused by the pop-up.  So, we prevented it by disabling Application.Warnings in VBA code.  The unwanted side-effect is that the credentials dialog is also suppressed.  If the credentials have been cleared for whatever reason, the query runs without authorization and fails.   Anyhow, It is now  moot, we have re-written using ADO.  Power Query never fails to disappoint.

Comment: You can disable Native Query prompts for all workbooks in the Options dialog. If you are able to set registry keys for the user (through an IT policy), you can also set a registry key to disable the prompt. The location in the registry depends on the version of Excel 2016 you're using (MSI or Click to Run), but adding the DWORD value DisableNativeDbQueryPrompt and setting it to 1 will disable it.